# Citing abstracts to cancelled conferences

Tags: citations, conference

Recently, many conferences have been cancelled, but in some cases (e.g. 50th Lunar and Planetary Science Conference) the abstracts accepted for the conference are avilable online, despite none of them having been presented. The abstracts contain useful information and I would like to cite some of them.

Are there any conventions for how to cite in this case? Do I need to make it clear that the citation only references the abstract? Beyond that, do I need to make it clear that I know that the abstract was never presented?